# libtool: 'make' command ends without errors but don't creates any executable

Tags: makefile, autotools, libtool

When I run 'make', in a project with autotools and libtool, the library is builded correctly, but the executable is not created in its path. This is the line generated by automake:

```
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O0   -o foo foo-foo.o ../libfoo/src/libfoo.la
```

This line doesn't print anything (even errors). There is something wrong with this Makefile.am?

```
bin_PROGRAMS=foo

foo_SOURCES= \
    foo.cc

foo_CPPFLAGS = \
    -I$(top_srcdir)/libfoo/include \
    -DLOCALEDIR=\"$(localedir)\"

foo_LDADD = \
    ../libfoo/src/libfoo.la \
    $(LIBINTL)
```

Comment: Maybe your `../libfoo/src/libfoo.la` should be relative to your builddir or top_builddir. For example $(builddir)/../libfoo/src/libfoo.la. That of course doesn't explain why you don't get an error. Why is foo.cc named foo-foo.o after compiling?

Comment: Hi, is not that, I really don't remember how I solved this problem right now, but the problem was the `../libtool` command was not the same that "/usr/bin/libtool", and when you execute `/bin/bash /usr/bin/libtool` the executable was generated succesfuly.

I think I solved using libtoolize